# Unable to pass class to add method due to abstract class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a series of record classes, 7 in total. These are abstracted from a base class, Record.
My factory creates the proper class, returning it to my main method.
Next I call Creator method which builds the master class; Container.
From this class, I perform specific DB tasks on each of the records. The goal is to package the Records
into the Container and pass to a Task Manager that creates a thread and works on the records in the container.
Everything works great, until I build the container.
The Container has 7 overloaded methods to add the record class, of a specific type, into the proper list.
This is failing, as the returned class from the RecordFactory is Record, rather than Record_40.
Without creating a switch/case as I have here, is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
//RecordFactory
public static class RecordFactory
{
    public static Record GetRecordClass(string recordType)
    {
        Type classType = Type.GetType("myClass.Record_" + recordType);
        return (Record)Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
    }
}

// Record
namespace myNamespace
{
    public abstract class Record
    {
        public void Deserialize(string input, int row);

        // Properties
        public abstract int Row { get; private set; }
        public abstract string Name { get; private set; }
        public abstract string OrderID { get; private set; }
        public abstract string CustomerID { get; private set; }
    }
}

// Record_40
    public class Record_40 : Record
    {
        public override void Deserialize(string input, int row)
        {
                Utility.Deserialize(input, row);
        }

        // Properties
        public override int Row { get; private set; }
        public override string Name { get; private set; }
        public override string OrderID { get; private set; }
        public override string CustomerID { get; private set; }
        public string TrackingNumber { get; private set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; private set; }
    }

// Container class
public sealed class Container
{
    private Container()
    {

    }

    private List<Record_30> _list_30 = new List<Record_30>();
    private List<Record_40> _list_40 = new List<Record_40>();
    private List<Record_50> _list_50 = new List<Record_50>();
    private List<Record_100> _list_100 = new List<Record_100>();
    private List<Record_200> _list_200 = new List<Record_200>();
    private List<Record_250> _list_250 = new List<Record_250>();
    private List<Record_300> _list_300 = new List<Record_300>();

    public void Add(Record_30 item) => _list_30.Add(item);
    public void Add(Record_40 item) => _list_40.Add(item);
    public void Add(Record_50 item) => _list_50.Add(item);
    public void Add(Record_100 item) => _list_100.Add(item);
    public void Add(Record_200 item) => _list_200.Add(item);
    public void Add(Record_250 item) =>  _list_250.Add(item);
    public void Add(Record_300 item) => _list_300.Add(item);

    public List<Record_30> Record30 => _list_30;
    public List<Record_40> Record40 => _list_40;
    public List<Record_50> Record50 => _list_50;
    public List<Record_100> Record100 => _list_100;
    public List<Record_200> Record200 => _list_200;
    public List<Record_250> Record250 => _list_250;
    public List<Record_300> Record300 => _list_300;

    public string OrderID { get; private set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; private set; }
}

public static class ContainerBuilder
{
    private static string _orderID;
    private static string _customerID;
    private static Container _container;

    public static void PopulateContainer(Record rec)
    {
        string _recordName = rec.GetType().Name;

        if ((rec.OrderID != _orderID) || 
            (rec.CustomerID != _customerID))
        {
            TaskManager.ProcessContainer(_container);
            _container = new Container();
        }
        switch(_recordName)
        {
            case "Record_30":
                _container.Add((Record_30)rec);
                break;
            case "Record_40":
                _container.Add((Record_40)rec);
                break;
            case "Record_50":
                _container.Add((Record_50)rec);
                break;
            case "Record_100":
                _container.Add((Record_100)rec);
                break;
            case "Record_200":
                _container.Add((Record_200)rec);
                break;
            case "Record_250":
                _container.Add((Record_250)rec);
                break;
            case "Record_300":
                _container.Add((Record_300)rec);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How this `PopulateContainer` is called?

Comment: ContainerBuilder.PopulateContainer(rec);
It is called after the GetRecordClass method

Comment: Just to name an alternative would be "visitor pattern" - but the accepted answer is probably more readable and simple.

Comment: You can use two `Dictionary`s in container, for example first can store mapping between `string` (type name) and `Type`, second can store list for a specific `Type` as `IList` and then you can add items by using dictionary indexes with fast `O(1)` lookups. Imho it's more cumbersome but also much more efficient than using `dynamic`. Something along the lines of: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jVDx7U

Comment: Thanks - I'll look at the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dynamic` to remove the `switch`:

```
public static void PopulateContainer(Record rec) {
    if ((rec.OrderID != _orderID) || (rec.CustomerID != _customerID)) {
        TaskManager.ProcessContainer(_container);
        _container = new Container();
    }
    _container.Add((dynamic)rec);
}
```

This approach ensures that the proper overload is called, at the expense of producing a run-time failure when an object of an unknown subclass is passed. `switch` has the same problem, but the unknown type is ignored by the `default` case. Consider writing a catch-all `Add(Record)` method that would trap additions of unknown subclasses, and provide appropriate diagnostics at run-time.

Comment: Thank you - I totally forgot about (dynamic)  - That fixed it. And thank you for the reminder on the catch-all method.